# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC web app returning bad request errors in some pages after deployment to IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, asp.net-core-identity, windows-server-2019

I have tried everything. I configured Windows Server 2019 according to Microsoft documentation and I successfully deployed a .NET 5 web application to the IIS.

I can get to the login page. I can even get to the forgot password page and they show themselves fine. However when I try to do any action (send the forgot password link or login to the page) I get a "Bad Request" from the server. I haven't found a way to explain why.

I have tried several, and I mean several things found Googling around but nothing helps. This include disabling https within the .NET Core application, trying to get a detailed error page using the `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` instruction inside Startup, etc etc but nothing works. I always receive this page trying to execute any action:

[image: IIS throwing bad request]

If someone could help or point me into the right direction, I will really, REALLY appreciate it.

Thank you

PD: In case it has anything to do with the problem, the error, at least the two that I can reproduce (because I can't even log in), happens, I think (maybe don't) when redirecting to another page in Microsoft Identity.

**EDIT**: code was asked by one of you. Thank you.

As you see, there's nothing specific in the forgot password screen for my application. This is scaffold code from Microsoft Identity. I even edited it and just let one line of code inside it, which is the default return code anyway as follow:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    return RedirectToPage("./ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
}
```

As you can see, there's nothing special with that code. Here's the html that calls it, again, is a scaffold of Microsoft Identity with little to no changes (by little, I mean, maybe some CSS and a new value of view data):

[image: Microsoft Identity Forgot Password Scaffold]

But then again, forgot password page actually shows and seems well in the front end, but immediately I try to enter my email and click enter in this page, (also, just a scaffold of Microsoft Identity):

[image]

Nothing happens. I receive the bad request. There's NO magic nor custom code here. Something silly is going on.

**EDIT II**: YES, locally it works perfectly. The strange behavior happens only when deployed to IIS.

**EDIT III**: I coded and enabled logging in my .NET Core APP and wrote that to a file, and I think I finally got, at least the error (not the reason yet):

[image: Anti Forgery Token Error]

But why?? Cookies are enabled in the server browser without avail, same issue. Someone has a better idea than disabling anti forgery rules to login and forgot password pages?

Thank you

Comment: This is very specific to an application, so if you cannot share its code somewhere for others to review, the question is not answerable. If you just need some hints, then disable IE's friendly HTTP error pages, and also enable ASP.NET Core logging. Both should help you learn about the actual error.

Comment: Hey @LexLi. Thank you for your willingness to help. I updated my answer with some code, but you'll see that there's nothing special nor custom this time, as I removed my logic in everything, and default Microsoft Identity code still gives the error. I also disabled IE's friendly HTTP error page, and now the page just comes blank. Nothing is shown. Please see my updated answer and let me know if you come with another idea. I'm working into enabling ASP.NET Core logging just about right now.

Comment: @LexLi I implemented logging in the app, and now I see the error. Please see my again, updated question and let me know if you come with a better idea. Thank you!

Comment: Erm..... the problem was Internet Explorer from Windows Server 2019. Once I connected to the IP using VPN from my local computer and used Chrome, all the problems went away. Jesuschrist. Thank you @LexLi

Comment: That's an interesting result. You might post that below as your own answer and accept it, which can help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, when I deployed the first version of my app into IIS, I thought it was a good idea to just browse it from the IIS link. Of course, in a new mounted Windows Server 2019, IE is still the default browser. I connected directly to the IP of my web app via VPN, but used Chrome this time. Guess what? All problems disappeared. Yes, it's a bad idea to try to use a modern framework like .NET Core Identity with IE.